# Freeing multiple buffers in destructor c++

Tags: c++

I've got an array of pointers as a member in my class.
I am using those pointers to allocate a certain number of buffers.

In the destructor I want to free this memory, but it seems like I am doing something wrong.

```
   //In the Constructor
   for(int i = 0; i< NUM_OF_BUFFERS; i++)
   {
      mBuffer[i] = new Uint8[BUFFERSIZE];
      memset(mBuffer[i], 0, BUFFERSIZE);
      mBufferState[i] = NULL;
   }



   //In the destructor
   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_BUFFERS; i++)
   {
      delete[] mBuffer[i];
   }
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to work.
If I am commenting those lines in the destructor out, the program runs fine, if I run it with those lines it seems to freeze.

Comment: forgot the member declaration!   Uint8 *mBuffer[NUM_OF_BUFFERS];

Comment: The code looks fine. What does not work? You can also edit your own questions if you want to clarify something.

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor?

Comment: For what it's worth, you could avoid the issue by not using dynamic memory management in the first place. Instead, use a `std::vector< std::vector<Uint8> > mBuffer;` and initialize it like `for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_BUFFERS; ++i ) { mBuffer.push_back( std::vector<Uint8>( BUFFERSIZE ) ); }`. No work needed in the destructor.

Comment: What Seth is really trying to say is [Look up the Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: I don't have a copy constructor @Frerich Raabe I'll give it a try

Comment: @user984308: If you "don't have one", then you actually do have one, but it's wrong, and you need to write a better one. Or stop writing code like it's C :-)

Comment: @user984308 Kerrek means that if you don't write a copy you'll be using the default, but if it's not working (and it easily happens as soon as you use pointers and structures)... you definitely need to write a custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code you posted, so the problem must be somewhere in the code you *didn't* post.

My bet would be on some out-of-bounds access that is clobbering the bookkeeping information required by the heap manager.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use some static analysis tool like [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/cppcheck) (it's free, multi platform and open source) and run it against your code.

You could even try [PVS Studio](http://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio/) if your code runs into Visual Studio (a very very nice tool).